# Building MySQL from source changes Makefile due to cmake

Tags: mysql, git, version-control, makefile, cmake

I am working on MySQL optimization with another researcher and we are using git for version control. The problem is that each of us has to compile those sources on separate machines and running **cmake .** generates different versions of makefile on our machine. If we think about the following cases

```
1. A changes source
2. A runs cmake, builds the source, and test performance
3. B pulls the code change
4. B changes source, runs cmake and builds the source
```

After the step 4, B will have a different version of Makefile and files such as cmake_install.cmake that depend on users and user paths.

For example, some of the files have the following diffs.

```
# The program to use to edit the cache.
-CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND = /usr/local/bin/ccmake
+CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND = /usr/bin/ccmake

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
-CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/dcslab/userA/mysql/mysql-5.6.21-original
+CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/dcslab/userB/mysql-5.6.21-original

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
-CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/dcslab/userA/mysql/mysql-5.6.21-original
+CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/dcslab/userB/mysql-5.6.21-original
```

These are all user-dependent paths generated by cmake commands. The direct way to resolve this conflict is to untrack Makefiles or any file generated by cmake after initially committing them. I am wondering if there is any better and legit way of managing projects using cmake for more than one user. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files generated by CMake are *machine-dependent*, so they will not work on any machine except one where they has been generated. Because of that, they are useless on for others and there is no needs to track them in git. There are two ways for achive this:

1. Tune [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for ignore files, generated by CMake, on commit. Patterns for such files are relatively simple and can be found by googling. Disadvantage of this approach is that files, generated by project's CMake scripts (`configure_file`, `add_custom_command`) will not be automatically ignored and will require explicit notion in `gitignore`
2. Perform *out-of-source* builds, that is not run `cmake` from source directory. CMake generates additional files only in build directory, correct project's CMake scripts also should follow this rule. So git repo will be clean without any gitignore patterns.

It is common practice to perform out-of-source build in `./build` subdirectory of source directory. In this case you can add `/build/**` to `gitignore`, and everything will work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I think both are wonderful ways of handling the problem that I have mentioned. It really helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

An important part of good engineering -- and especially in research -- is reproducability. It is unfortunate that the code you are working on can be influenced by the environment in which it is built (you may want to look at the [Bazel](http://bazel.io/) for future projects to reduce external dependencies). Given that this code already has this external dependency problem, you can at least counter the effects by using a consistent environment via virtualization. In particular, you may want to take a look at [Docker](http://www.docker.com), which would allow you and your collaborators to build/run code using a common system image, thereby ensuring that all builds and executions are derived from a predictable, consistent environment.

Comment: Introducing Docker would be a good way. However, since we are working on storage performance, I am a little worried that virtualization might have an impact on performance measured by DB benchmarks. :( What do you think?

Comment: @CoderSpinoza this should be no more of an issue than regular process/thread context switching in a regular OS, especially since Docker implements virtualization using cgroups (at least on Linux) which allows this virtualization to be implemented with very little overhead. In fact, using a container platform like Docker may, in fact, allow you to make more precise measurements, since the system provides you with additional control over resource allocation and very clear accounting. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/runmetrics/